# Conditional intensity of a generalized Poisson process

Tags: probability-theory, poisson-process, point-processes

Assume that we have a temporal point process on the interval [0, 1], where the number of events $N$ is distributed according to some PMF $p(N = n)$. Conditioned on $N$, the arrivals times of the events $t_i$ (for $i = 1, \dots, N$) are sampled independently from a distribution with a PDF $f(t)$, supported on the interval $[0, 1]$.

How can I obtain the conditional intensity $\lambda^*(t)$ of this point process?

I know that in the special case of $p(N = n) =\textrm{Poisson}(n; \mu)$ and $f(t) = \textrm{Uniform}(t; [0, 1])$ we obtain the Poisson process with conditional intensity $\lambda^*(t) = \mu$.
Similarly, in case $p(N = n) =\textrm{Poisson}(n; \mu)$ and $f(t)$ is an arbitrary density on $[0, 1]$, we obtain the inhomogeneous Poisson process with conditional intensity $\lambda^*(t) = \mu f(t)$ (see, e.g., Theorem 2 in [this paper](https://web.ics.purdue.edu/%7Epasupath/PAPERS/2011pasB.pdf)).
I wonder if this result can be generalized to an arbitrary PMF $p(N = n)$.

I'm also not sure how such generalization of the Poisson process is called in the literature, and I will appreciate any pointers in this direction. So far, I found only [one paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167947318300811) (first paragraph of Section 4.3) that refers to this generalized Poisson process as "cluster models" and cites "An Introduction to the Theory of Point Processes, Vol I" by Daley & Vere-Jones. However, I was unable to find any references to "cluster models" in the book.

Comment: Here is the answer for the special case, when $N$ follows the Negative Binomial distribution https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/383142/intensity-function-in-poisson-random-effect-model